# eclipse menu contribution

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to add a menu  to the eclipse menubar in a RCP application and that menu will be shown active based on some condition(e.g return value of some method) in Java code .Please let me know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_RCP_How-to#Menu) you find some short examples. Maybe that is enough to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

A menu can not be enabled/disabled directly based on an expression - that is only possible for the menu items themselves.

To enable/disable a menu item, have a look at [Command Core Expressions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions) in the Eclipse Wiki...